# Connect to amazon mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

I've followed the AWS [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html) on settings up a database connections, but still receive this error:

```
mysql -h <hostname> -P <port> -u <username> -p <password>

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbs.cmlxeidulru1.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)
```

The connection is using a [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html),  which appears to be the only (free) option.  The subnet and security groups are their default options, though I can't tell if I've configured them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS entry you've posted points to a public IP so check that your database security group opens port 3306 to your IP (check your IP using `curl curlmyip.com`, for example).

Comment: Thanks -- sorry if this is a silly question, but I want any computer to be able to query this database (it will power a website).  Is there a way to set it so that any machine can make the query?

Comment: You can open port 3306 in the security group to any address. This is NOT recommended. If the database powers a website you just need to authorize the IP address of the web server.